# Hive orc vectorization union all performance

Tags: hadoop, hive, vectorization

I am running a map only query like "select something from personel where name='aaa'" on a orc+zlib table on the cluster and if I check the EXPLAIN results I can see execution mode is "Vectorized".

If I run a simple map only union all query like "select something from personel where name='aaa' union all select something from personel where name='bbb'" then vectorization is not active for this query in the EXPLAIN results and query duration gets longer.

What might be the reason this result and what is the relation between union all and vectorization?

Comment: In that specific example, do you have a valid reason for scanning the data files *twice* instead of using a single-pass query like `select ... where name ='aaa' or name ='bbb'`?

Comment: Be sure yes. My example seems meaningless but union all is so important for our case and we couldnt figure out how vectorization is related with union all.